# Linking Page manager & views using taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels, views, chaos-tool-suite

Here is what I have done:

1. I created a taxonomy term called "section" with several terms 'section 1, section 2, etc...'.
2. I modified the standard 'Article' type to include a field using a taxonomy term list and generated test articles with the taxonomy terms included.
3. I created a view with a content pane. The title, body, node id and taxonomy term field are included in the field list. The pane is set as follows:Link to view: No; Use Panel path: No; Argument input: from context and set to the taxonomy term name.  A contextual filter is set to 'Content: section (field_section)' with a validation set to the taxonomy name from the 'section' vocabulary using the term id with the term name converted to term id.  When I enter a term name in the preview, it displays the correct content.
4. I created a custom page in page manager set to the path /sections/%section. It contains a rule that the type must be an article.  It contains a variant called 'section layout' with a contexts relationship for a 'Taxonomy term from Node (on Node: section)'. The Summary of Contexts includes argument 1 with all of the node fields and an additional set of fields for 'Taxonomy term from Node (on Node: section)'.
5. In the panel section I identified a two column layout with the view content pane described above in column one, and 'who's online' in column two so that the layout will show two columns when I use it.

When  I pick one of my articles from content, it calls up the article with the the url set to '/sections/section-1/article_name, but the page view is not implemented (the two column format is not displayed).

Here is what I think should be happening:

1. When I select an article for display, the url should be intercepted by the custom page '/sections/%section' and the fields from the article covered in the summary of contexts should be available to the view.
2. The view should be obtaining the taxonomy term from the 'section' field in the article through the context filter and returning articles with the same value to the panel.
3. The panel should create the two column format with the articles displayed in the first column and the 'who's online" in the second.

Instead, I get the original article.

Questions:

1. Do I have how the information is passed correct?  (page manager intercepts the url to handle it, It passes the info to the view selected by the panel, the gets the data through the argument input and selects the correct articles using the taxonomy term it finds in the arguments, the view is then rendered through the panel content layout.)
2. Am I missing any other required setting? (Do I have everything set correctly and have I included everything?  Are more settings required than I mention here?)
3. I assume that the panel is not getting results of the view and is passing the url back to the core and that is why it renders as a standard article. Is this correct?
4. Any suggestions as to why the view is not handled by page manager?

Any assistance is deeply appreciated.  I have been wrestling with passing taxonomy terms int o a view through the url and through page manager unsuccessfully for quite a while.

Comment: Just a comment. I suggest, if you can, be more explicit with your questions. there are lots of people that can help you, and making questions more explicit, will be more helpful for they. Is only my humble opinion (maybe is not a problem for they).

Comment: Thanks, I can break out separate questions, but everything is connected to the attempt to get page manager and views to work together.  Tutorials all work demonstrate with users, not taxonomies. I can get the view to work, but not through the content pane with context from the panel and page manager.